# set recordsFiltered in HTML from json response

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I am using `Yajra/DataTable`. I want to filter my DataTable and find `total number of rows` after filtered table is loaded. I have done some stuff but it is returning all `row_counts` from DataTables. How can I only achieve it. Please suggest me.

Here is ajax call response in which I get `recordsFiltered` as `filtered_counts` but how can I set it:

[image]

```
 var usersPreviewTable;
    function initializeUsersTable() {

        if(usersPreviewTable) {
            usersPreviewTable.ajax.reload();
            return;
        }

        usersPreviewTable = $('#datatables').DataTable({
            searching: false,
            responsive: true,
            ajax:{
                url:'/users/json',
                type:'GET',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: function (d) {
                    var criteria = preparePreviewCriteria();
                    for (var field in criteria) {
                        d[field] = criteria[field];
                    }
                }
            },
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'id', orderable: false,
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'username', name: 'username',
                    render: function (cellData, type, rowData, meta) {
                        return '<a href="/users/' + rowData.id + '/edit" class="plain-anchor">' + cellData + '</a>'
                    }
                },
                {data: 'phone', name: 'phone'},
                {
                    data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at', render: function (cellData, type, rowData, meta) {
                    return moment(cellData).format('DD MMM YY')
                }
                },
                {
                    data: null, orderable: false,
                    render: function (cellData, type, rowData, meta) {
                        var form = '<form id="deleteForm-' + rowData.id + '" method="POST" action="/users/ ' + rowData.id + '" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display:inline">' +
                            '<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">' +
                            '{{ csrf_field() }}' +
                            '<input type="hidden" name="filter" value="[]"> ' +
                            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-round btn-fab btn-fab-mini" title="Delete User" onclick="openConfirmDelete(&quot;Confirm delete?&quot;, ' + rowData.id + ', deleteConfirmationCallback)"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button> ' +
                            '</form>';

                        return '<a href="/users/' + rowData.id + '/edit" class="btn btn-success btn-round btn-fab btn-fab-mini"' +
                            'title="Edit User"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a> ' + (rowData.session ? '<button href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-round btn-fab btn-fab-mini kickOut" title="Kick Out User" id="kickOut-' + rowData.id + '" onclick="kickoutUser(event)"> <i class="material-icons">input</i></a> ' +
                                '</button>' : '')
                        /*+ form*/
                    }
                }
            ],
            language: {
                emptyTable: 'No data to display',
                processing: '<img class=\'loader-img\' src=\'/images/golden_loader.gif\'>'
            },
            initComplete: function() {
                var tableinfo = usersPreviewTable.page.info();
                var total = tableinfo.recordsTotal;
                $('#usersCount').text( 'Filtered Users : ' + total )
            }
        });
    }

    $('#filterUsers').on('click', function (event) {
        initializeUsersTable();
        var tableinfo = usersPreviewTable.page.info();
        var total = tableinfo.recordsFiltered;
        $('#usersCount').text('Filtered Users : ' + total)
        console.log(total);
    });
```

In `initComplete` I get total rows in my table. But in `$('#filterUsers').on('click', function (event)` I want to get filtered data say for example 5. However I am getting recordsFiltered as my expected result in json response I am not able to get it inside this method. Please suggest me , how can I do it?

Comment: you can set a variable outside the initializeUsersTable function and then set it to recordsFiltered in json response. and then use it inside the click method.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now question is little bit modified, I am getting `filteredRowCounts` but when I click twice on `filterUsers` button. It is because of `initComplete` method may be. Because when I click on `filterUsers` button it again initialises it and original DataTable is set again that's why I am getting all Row Counts on first click and filtered row counts on second click. So, what is other solution for preventing DataTable from Reinitialisation. Is there any alternative for initComplete method? Please suggest me.

Comment: why do you need to Reinitialise the table? are you trying to use the search functionality?